# Type constraints in interface apply to base class

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I have a base class that defines a generic method like this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public T DoSomething<T> ()
    { ... }
}
```

As this class is by a third-party and does not come with an interface, I am defining an interface that defines the actually needed methods from that class. That way I get loose coupling and can actually exchange that third-party class with something else. For this example, consider the following interface:

```
public interface ISomething
{
    T DoSomething<T> ()
        where T : Foo;
}
```

As you can see, it defines the same method but also applies a type constraint on the type parameter, which comes from some other requirements that are not relevant to this.

Next, I define a subtype of `BaseClass` which also implements `ISomething`. This class will be used as the usual implementation behind the interface–while the interface will be what the rest of the application will be accessing.

```
public class Something : BaseClass, ISomething
{
    // ...
}
```

As the `DoSomething` in `BaseClass` already supports any type parameter `T`, it should especially support a type parameter which is a subtype of `Foo`. So one would expect that a subtype of `BaseClass` already implements the interface. However I get the following error:

> The constraints for type parameter 'T' of method 'BaseClass.DoSomething()' must match the constraints for type parameter 'T' of interface method 'ISomething.DoSomething()'. Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead.

Now, I have two possibilities; the first one is to do what the error suggests and implement the interface explicitely. The second is to hide the base implementation using `new`:

```
// Explicit implementation
T ISomething.DoSomething<T> ()
{
    return base.DoSomething<T>();
}

// Method hiding
public new T DoSomething<T>()
    where T : Foo
{
    return base.DoSomething<T>();
}
```

Both work, although I’d probably prefer the second solution to keep the method accessible from the class itself. However it still leaves the following question:

Why do I have to re-implement the method when the base type already implements it with a less-strict (read: none) type constraint? Why does the method need to be implemented exactly as it is?

**edit:** To give the method a bit more meaning, I changed the return type from `void` to `T`. In my actual application, I have both generic arguments and return values.

Comment: Is having methods with the same signatures the same as implementing an interface?

Comment: Same question is asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634989/why-do-i-need-to-redeclare-type-constraint-in-generic-subclass?rq=1 (although I'm not voting to close this one since it doesn't seem a consensus was reached in the original), personally I'm partial to Hans Passant's response there but really you're probably going to need someone like Lippert to weigh in if you want a definitive answer

Comment: Why do the signatures have to match? Because something that is referencing an instance of `Something` as `BaseClass` could attempt to call `DoSomething` with a type paramater that does not inherit `Foo`.

Comment: @Ginosaji: And what would be the problem with that?

Comment: Doing so would violate the `Foo` constraint on `ISomething`. It's difficult to demonstrate with your example because it's just an action. But imagine `DoSomething<T>` returned an instance of `T`. How would you guarantee that the return value of `DoSomething<T>` inherited from `Foo`?

Comment: @kekekela Thanks for the link! I had a hard time searching for similar topics.

Comment: @Ginosaji If `T DoSomething<T>()` is implemented in `BaseClass`, then I can be sure to get a `Foo` if I call `DoSomething<Foo>()`.

Comment: @Ginosaji: That would be a different method. We are talking about the method as given.

Comment: Note that the given method is just an example, I have methods that both take and give `T`s.

Comment: @poke: Then you 'd certainly have variance problems with those methods like Ginosaji says.

Comment: I don't see any logical problem with the example presented. I can imagine, in a limited capacity, that it may be difficult to build that into c# and that is why it is not possible, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly the given code could be compiled and run safely:

When a `Something` instance is typed as `Something` or as `BaseClass` the compiler would allow any type for `T`, while when the same instance is typed as `ISomething` it would allow just types inheriting `Foo`. In both cases you get static checking and runtime safety as usual.

**In fact, the above scenario is *exactly* what happens when you implement `ISomething` explicitly.** So let's see what arguments we can make for and against the current state of affairs.

For:

- the proposed solution would not be applicable to all cases; it depends on the exact method signatures (is the type argument covariant? contravariant? invariant?)
- it doesn't require the specification to be amended with new text stating how such cases are handled
- it makes the code self-documenting -- you don't have to learn said text; the current rules regarding explicit interface implementation are enough
- it does not impose development costs on the C# compiler team (documentation, feature implementation, testing, etc)

Against:

- you need to type more

Considering the above and additionally the fact that this is not an everyday scenario, IMHO the conclusion to be reached is clear: this *might* be nice to have, but it certainly doesn't warrant going out of your way to implement it.

Comment: Thank you for actually trying to answer the *why* :) I understand that it would involve some effort to get this working in the language, but then again that is true for every new language feature. But I also understand that this is a rare use case, and both explicit implementation and method hiding solve it just fine. It was just odd to stumble on this, as I actually expected it to work. — Do you have any example for me where contravariance of the type argument applies? This is also somewhat related to the comment by @Ginosaji in the question comments (see also my reply there).

Answer (score 3):

Try using composition instead of inheritance to implement `Something`:

```
public class Something : ISomething
{
    private readonly BaseClass inner = ...;

    void DoSomething<T>() where T : Foo
    {
        inner.DoSomething<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: This cannot be a general solution, it has **lots** of problems (e.g. is not a `BaseClass`, requires keeping duplicate state, has no access to `protected` members, etc).

Comment: @Jon Understood about the limitations. But if the OP wants loose coupling, there's no need for it to be a `BaseClass`, in fact it shouldn't be. To access protected members, he can extend it and widen access to the members, then wrap an instance of that class instead (crufty, I realize). Don't see where the duplicate state you mentioned is though.

Comment: Assuming that `BaseSomething` has state, in such scenarios you can easily be forced to duplicate it. Anyway my point is about the general case (and only because you offered a concrete solution -- there are lots of unknowns here).

Comment: I agree that composition can be useful to solve this, but it’s not really a good solution for me. Only a few of the methods defined in the interface are conflicting with the methods defined in `BaseClass`, so composing it would mean to replicate *every* single method. And as Jon said, I would lose the ability to access protected members which is necessary with the current implementation. As such explicitely implementing the interface or hiding methods is more appropriate for me. — Btw. I do realize that I left a lot unknowns, but that was intended as I am more interested in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want with the code below. By including the type parameter in the interface defenition you can make it covariant which seems to satisfy the compiler. The `Base` class remains untouched and you are able to shadow the `Base` implementation and implement the interface with a single method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var something = new Something<Foo>();
        var baseClass = (BaseClass)something;
        var isomething = (ISomething<Foo>)something;

        var baseResult = baseClass.DoSomething<Bar>();
        var interfaceResult = isomething.DoSomething<Bar>();
        var result = something.DoSomething<Bar>();
    }
}

class Foo 
{
}

class Bar : Foo
{
}

class BaseClass
{
    public T DoSomething<T>()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

interface ISomething<out T> where T : Foo
{
    T DoSomething<T>();
}

class Something<T> : BaseClass, ISomething<T> where T : Foo
{
    public new T DoSomething<T>()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

---

Or if you really don't want to specify `Foo` in the instantiation

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var something = new Something();
        var baseClass = (BaseClass)something;
        var isomething = (ISomething)something;

        var baseResult = baseClass.DoSomething<Bar>();
        var interfaceResult = isomething.DoSomething<Bar>();
        var result = something.DoSomething<Bar>();
    }
}

class Foo 
{
}

class Bar : Foo
{
}

class BaseClass
{
    public T DoSomething<T>()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

interface ISomething
{
    T DoSomething<T>;
}

interface ISomething<S> : ISomething where S : Foo
{
    new R DoSomething<R>() where R : Foo;
}

class Something : BaseClass, ISomething
{
    public new T DoSomething<T>()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I do need the generic methods and cannot instantiate the object depending on which type I need to operate on (i.e. the `Doer` or `Something` class is not generic itself).

Comment: @poke, as you can see in my extended answer, you can instantiate it based on `Foo`, not the type you need it to operate on. Since you must know `Foo` already to place the constraint on the interface I believe this satisfies your requirement.

Comment: @poke or with a bit of indirection that can be avoided at a cost.